# spinnaker UI is stucked on authentication and finally gets timed out

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

[image]I have noticed a request is going with wrong URL ,please find in image attached, in place of http://ip:9000 it is routing to hhttp://ip:9000

Comment: Is this the "Spinnaker for GCP" deployment from Google Marketplace?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "in place of http://ip:9000 it is routing to hhttp://ip:9000". As I can see at `http://35.222.119.229:9000/` some web server is running, but no access "403 Forbidden".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a typo in the override URL for deck to be hhttp instead of http.

Answer (score 0):

Where have you installed spinnaker is it on GCP or AWS EC2, moreover this mostly occurs due to automatic change of the baseurl in the multicloud provider you are using, for you to avoid this later on, you have to attach an Elastic IP address to your EC2 if you have installed spinnaker on AWS EC2. Moreover for you to edit the existing IP use vi config in your terminal to edit the current baseURL with the pubic DNS in your EC2, hal deploy apply, to modify changes then do hal deploy connect for port forwarding the try to reload the spinnaker UI again